# How do I create recursive custom tags in YAMLDotNet

Tags: c#, recursion, yamldotnet

I'm working with YAML in C#, using YamlDotNet.  I've created a custom tag that will deserialize to a simple object supporting string interpolation.  Let's say the tag is "!StrInterp", and its structure is a template string and a sequence of args to interpolate.  In the YAML it looks something like this:

```
Blah: !StrInterp
  Template: "My {0} says {1}"
  Args: ["dog", "woof"]
```

That YAML structure maps to a simple C# class like this:

```
public class StrInterp
{
    public string Template { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Args { get; set; }
}
```

Got this working by adding a simple tag mapping to the deserializer, like this:

```
var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder()
  .WithTagMapping("!StrInterp", typeof(StrInterp)
  .Build()
```

So far so good.

What I want to do is extend that so that the args can themselves be !StrInterp tags, e.g.:

```
Blah: !Str
  Template: "My {0} says {1}"
  Args: ["dog", !Str { Template: "{0} and {1}", Args: ["woof", "arf"] }]
```

It seems like I need some kind of variant type for the Args list, so that an arg could be either an !Str tag or a simple scalar string, but I'm not aware of any such type in C#.

Is there a way to do this?  Thank you!

Comment: does this `public IList<object> Args { get; set; }` help?

Comment: yes, that does work!  so simple.  thank you!